# i have 5 array in my dataArray and want to add all in my db but only 1st value save in database... anyone know soln?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

bulkImport(req, res) {
console.log(req.body);

```
    let dataArray = req.body.datafile;
    if (dataArray) {
        for (let i = 1; i <= dataArray.length; i++) {
            let name = dataArray[i][1];
            let flipkart_names = dataArray[i][2];
            let amazon_names = dataArray[i][3];

            Category.create({
                name: name,
                flipkart_names: flipkart_names,
                amazon_names: amazon_names,
                status: '1',
            })
```

i have 5 array in my dataArray and want to add all in my db but only 1st value save in database... anyone know soln?

Comment: it looks like you use some ORM, check bulkCreate function, don't create records one by one

Comment: Can you share the dataArray sample?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara                                              
name,flipkart_names,amazon_names
bulb,flipbulb,amzbulb
test,fliptest,amztest
bulk,flipbulk,amzbulk

Comment: @I2ysho i want to upload multiple row in my db.